# "The Application is incorrectly configured" on published game

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, google-oauth, google-play-games

I set up Google Play Games Services through the Google Play Developer Console by following the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling).

I went through the troulbeshooting guide [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting).

If i run my app through eclipse, it can connect fine to Play Games.  However now the update is released and if I download it from the Play Store it cannot connect.

I verified that my SHA1 from the android export matches what is in the developer console.  I even tried linking a new app with the SHA1 and it says: "This client ID is globally unique and is already in use."

I am now panicking because my game is live and can't connect.  Help!

EDIT:

I added my client ID through the Google Play Developer Console, not the Google Developer Console.  I removed the Client ID that was in the Google Developer Console.

[image]
[image]
[image]

### [image]

[image: from Google Play Developer Console]

Edit:

I cannot add a new client in GDC, i get an error about "duplicate fingerprint":
[image]

Comment: Did you create the Client IDs through the Game Services > Linked Apps tab of Google Play Developer Console, or directly through Google Developers Console?  If you do it the second way, it may not work.

Comment: Yes the Client ID was created through the Google Play Developer Console - Linked Apps tab, no the GDC.

Comment: So you have two client IDs, correct?  One for your published app and one for your development key?

Comment: No, I have 2 linked apps, but only 1 Application ID.  If I go to Google Developer Console and click on APIs & auth -> credentials it has no Client IDs.

Comment: Ok it looks like you are in a bad state here regarding the syncing of Client IDs between GPDC and GDC.  I'd suggest deleting all of the Linked Apps from GPDC and all of the Client IDs from GDC.  Then recreate the linked apps through GDC (one with debug key, one with prod key). 


I've seen this before and that should fix it.

Comment: The problem is that I already published the app and the play games services, and it won't let me delete linked apps that have been published.

Comment: Can you delete and re-add all Client IDs in GDC?

Comment: @hatboysam I have removed all the clients already, and unsure even how to get them back.  I cannot add a new client in GDC, i get an error about "duplicate fingerprint": http://i.stack.imgur.com/XLsUo.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before altering / adding new API clients, make sure that you have checked the following:

- IS your play games project published?
- Or, are the accounts you are using for testing included on the testers list?
- Are you signing your app correctly? If you are using your debug keystore in a released game, the app will not correctly be able to authenticate.

At any rate, deleting clients could fix working apps if you have already published and I'd hate to give you advice that breaks stuff. That said, if you're sure you need to create / recreate your client, move on.

The reason you are encountering the "This client ID is globally unique and is already in use." issue is that there exists a client with the same package name and SHA-1 hash in **any** Google Developer console project (not necessarily a Google Play Games project, not necessarily the current project, and not necessarily a project for your account if you are working on teams). This is because the combination of package name and SHA-1 hash must be unique for authentication.

At any rate, it's possible that the project still has a client (for Android) created that needs to be removed. This means that you must either remove the "bad" client from the developer console, re-sign your app with a new keystore, or use a different package name.

#### Option 1 - Removing clients

Although this is the most destructive option, it may be a good approach if you already removed clients from the Play Games Developer console and don't want to change your configuration.

Access your project from https://console.developers.google.com because this will give you a superset of the clients created from the play games console and will have an according project. Select the APIs & Auth -> Credentials section. From here, remove any Android clients you intend to replace.

Return to https://play.google.com/apps/publish and select your games project. You should now be able to add another client.

#### Option 2 - Create a new keystore

This is best covered in the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html). After changing your keystore, you will be able to add another client using the new keystore signature.

#### Option 3 - Change the package name

You must update com.yourname.app with something other than com.yourname.app. This means renaming folders in your Android project, changing includes and package namespaces, and updating your project's AndroidManifest.xml.

After changing any of these, you should be able to create a working Google API project and get your app ready.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!  

Option 1: I show in my original post (with pictures) that I tried this and it does not work.  I deleted it from GDC.  When I return to GPDC and try to add a new one I get "The Client ID is globally unique and is already in use."  Am I doing this incorrectly?

Options 2 & 3: Is it possible to do these without completely starting over and losing all ratings and downloads?  Wouldn't this involve deleting my current game off of Google Play, and uploading it as a new game?

Comment: Which signing certificate is causing you the issue? Release or Debug? Also, check again on Option 1, it's easy to overlook a rogue instance of an Android API client in the developer console, you must delete all instances in all projects signed with the same key before you can publish.

Comment: The release certificate is the issue.  I have a game that is released on the Google Play Store and when people try to log in the get an error: "The application is incorrectly configured".  I have deleted all clients from the APIs & Auth -> Credentials section.  I have deleted all projects as well.  There is nothing left in there. http://i.stack.imgur.com/Te5nq.png

Comment: Does this mean only options 2&3 are available? Will I need to delete my game from Play Games and reupload it as a new game?

Comment: Can you create a new client now with your existing key? It sounds like you opted for option 1 (on purpose or accident because your live clients are breaking). For option 2, you would be able to create an additional client that will work with your app because the combination of signing cert + package name would be unique without affecting the live apps. Option 3 could require republishing, I'm not an expert in that area...

Comment: You should not need to delete your game to reupload it.

Comment: Do you use ProGuard to obfuscate  your app?  There was a problem with the screening of the application's use of games APIs (such as if you have configured achievements, but never call unlock().  If you are still having problems, can you provide the package name?

Comment: @class I cannot create a new client with my existing key.  I removed all clients from GDC, and still if I try to create a new client I get "This client ID is globally unique and already in use"   I do not want to use a new key because using a new key means I would have to upload this as a new game and I would lose my reviews etc.   From other comments I have seen with other people who had this issue they contacted someone from google who was able to fix something on the account.

Comment: I do not use ProGuard.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried deleting the console project related with your play service game installed application ?

Comment: I have deleted all clients from the APIs & Auth -> Credentials section. I have deleted all projects as well. There is nothing left in there. 
When I return to GPDC and try to add the client a I get the error " This client ID is globally unique and is already in use."

Answer (score 1):

Have you only one account?

"This client ID is globally unique and is already in use."

Maybe someone is using your sha1... or you with another account

Comment: I do have multiple google accounts however only one have I created any Client IDs.  I logged into all accounts and checked them for any lingering ones however none of them have any.